# (Sub)Domain pointing to MyFritz-Adress

Tags: domain, subdomain, cname

Following situation: I got a server at home which runs a NextCloud Docker, which is reachable through Port `8080`. Since I need to make it accessable for others (without VPN) and I got a DS-Lite + IPv6 connection, I used the MyFritz-Adress and PortForwarding to access it from outside my network via

```
http://server.XXXXXXXX.myfritz.net:12345
```

where `server` is my device and `XXXXXXXX.myfritz.net` is the MyFritz-Adress.
This works perfectly fine. But since this is quiet ugly, I wanted to use my domain `habun.de`, which I purchased from Hostinger.com, to make it prettier.

For that I made a CNAME DNS-Record

```
Type: CNAME
Name: pine
Priority: 0
Points to: pine.XXXXXXXX.myfritz.net
TTL: 14400 (default)
```

Then I added `http://pine.habun.de` to the `DNS-Rebind-Protetion` and waited around 24h (DNS Propagation?). In theory I should be able to access my Cloud now from `http://pine.habun.de:8080` but I can't... FireFox says "Server not found" (Tried cleaning cache and other browser as well)

So I tried two other DNS-Records

```
Type: CNAME
Name: home
Priority: 0
Points to: XXXXXXXX.myfritz.net
TTL: 14400 (default)
```

where `https://home.habun.de` should lead me to my FritzBox and

```
Type: CNAME (ALIAS)
Name: @
Priority: 0
Points to: XXXXXXXX.myfritz.net
TTL: 14400 (default)
```

where `https://habun.de` should lead me to my FritzBox as well.
Added both hostnames to `DNS-Rebind-Protection and waited 24h again, but still can't access my FritzBox... Same error as before.

Then I asked the support of Hostinger and they recommended deleting the default A Record, which I did and waited again 24h, but still the same error...

Right now I only have the 3 CNAME, a bunch of default CAA and 2 NS Records. The NameServers are the default NameServers of Hostinger.

I looked at various instructions but they all said I can just make a CNAME Record pointing to the MyFritz-adress... Did I overlook something or does anyone have an idea what could be the issue?

**Edit:**
`habun.de`is the actual domain I have and the nameservers are the default nameservers of Hostinger

```
ns1.dns-parking.com
ns2.dns-parking.com
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Turned out that everything was correctly setup and the issue was with Hostinger. My domain wasn't delegated to 'de' correctly. Solved by temporarily switching NameServer and then back to Hostinger NameServes, which resynced my domain. Now everything works as it should.
Solution came from @user1686 (see the discussion in the comments to his/her post).

Comment: Is `habun.de` the actual domain name you've purchased or just an example?

Comment: It is the actual domain name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `habun.de` is your real domain, it is currently **not delegated** in the `de` zone at all, meaning DNS resolvers don't even get to see your CNAME records.

(In other words, the pointer from `de` to `habun.de` is broken.)

The NS records at the root of your zone are mostly irrelevant – what matters is the NS records that your registrar (Hostinger) submits to the parent `de` registry, where the actual delegation to your nameservers is set up. Right now, however, all of the nameservers for `de` report that they have no NS delegation records for `habun.de` at all.

What the `de` zone (and the registry's WHOIS database) instead has is, unusually, just an A record:

```
habun.de. IN A 93.180.69.101
```

(This points to an IP address belonging to "PCextreme B.V." in the Netherlands.)

Normally this should not happen – there should only be NS (and optionally DS) records at this position. It is not unusual for A/AAAA records to be uploaded to the parent zone as "glue" records, but they must be on a subdomain (e.g. if the NS records had `example.com. NS ns1.example.com.`, then the registry would necessarily have `ns1.example.com. A` as well).

You should review the "Domain nameservers" configuration at Hostinger (which is somewhere separate from the DNS records section).

---

"24 hour DNS propagation" is *mostly* a myth, as active propagation only happens between the authoritative nameservers where you're editing the DNS records (e.g. Hostinger's ns1/ns2/ns…) and generally takes a few minutes at most. The rest of the world queries everything "on demand" – your DNS records are either a) unknown until someone asks for them, in which case the new value will be seen immediately, or b) the old value is cached, in which case the old value will be seen for *at most* the "TTL" that it had before the change. (If the domain didn't exist, that fact is cached for the "minimum TTL" set in your SOA record, which is indeed often set to 24 hours.)

The actually important part of the above is the distinction between "authoritative servers" and "the rest of the world". Before waiting hours for caches to expire, you can start by *directly* querying the authoritative nameservers that are supposed to hold your data, and make sure they report a value that looks correct. For example, to check your CNAME entry directly at Hostinger:

```
C:\>  nslookup pine.habun.de ns1.dns-parking.com

$ host pine.habun.de ns1.dns-parking.com
```

and to check the delegation records from `de` to your domain:

```
C:\>  nslookup -q=NS habun.de a.nic.de

$ host -t NS habun.de a.nic.de

$ dnstracer -s . habun.de
```

It is also a good idea to temporarily reduce your record TTLs if you plan to experiment with a bunch of changes. For example, you could set a subdomain's TTL to 5 minutes (and set the SOA "minttl" to 5m as well), wait for the caches to forget the old record with its old TTL, and once that's done, you'll only need to wait at most 5 minutes to see your changes worldwide.

Comment: I added the current nameservers in an edit. I guess they are somehow wrong, even though they are the default nameservers of Hostinger.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of those nameservers having been configured at Hostinger? The problem isn't with them being wrong; the problem is that they're not specified _at all_ where they should be specified.

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: Yeah, that looks okay, so the problem is with Hostinger not having correctly submitted them to the `de` registry. (Which should be automatic.) I would maybe try temporarily changing them to something else, waiting for the change to show up in DNS (either WHOIS or the "a.nic.de" queries in the post will show whether the change has taken place), and then changing them back. If that doesn't solve the issue, contact Hostinger tech support and have them fix it.

Comment: Okay, thank you
I will try that and will keep you updated :)

Comment: (To clarify, the _first_ screenshot with the "DNS / Nameservers" section is the important one, while the records shown in the second one aren't really used for much at all – though both lists should match nevertheless.)

Comment: One more question, to what should/can I change them?

Comment: Technically it doesn't matter, as the goal is just to trigger a resync of those values from Hostinger's systems to the DE registry when you change them back to Hostinger servers after – but the system will probably expect names of working DNS servers authoritative for that domain, so I would temporarily sign up at some DNS hosting provider such as dns.he.net (or AWS Route53, or Google Cloud DNS, or the DNS hosting services of Digitalocean/Vultr/Linode, or whatever else happens to be available) and add the domain there, then specify that service's nameservers in Hostinger.

Comment: After the change (and after the change back), use `whois habun.de` (or their [webwhois](https://www.denic.de/webwhois/?lang=en)) to verify that the registry received the new nameserver names. This might take up to an hour with some registries. If nothing seems to work, tell Hostinger that "WHOIS is showing wrong nameservers" or something along those lines.

Comment: It actually worked!!! Thank you!!! Switched to Google Cloud and then back and now it works!!!

Comment: (To be clear, there is no requirement to actually return to Hostinger servers, so you can stay with Google Cloud as the DNS hosting provider if you want – it really depends on which control panel is more convenient to manage and offers the features you want, e.g. some support DNSSEC or less common record types or "ALIAS" pseudo-records or a command-line tool/API while others don't.)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. As I am pretty new to all that stuff, I'll take my time to go over each step one by one. Probably will take a look at a few options in the next few days. For example I didn't see the possibility to add an SSL encryption in Hostinger (without a hosting plan).

Comment: That's because SSL really has nothing to do with domain registration *or* with DNS hosting – it needs to be done wherever the actual service is hosted. So it wouldn't make sense for Hostinger to offer it for anything but their own managed services. (At most, they could be a reseller of SSL certificates, but that's no longer very useful with Let's Encrypt being a thing now.) In your case, SSL would be set up either in the Nextcloud Docker container or in a reverse proxy if you're using one.

Comment: Could you help me with another issue? https://superuser.com/questions/1773123/cname-record-not-working-in-local-network

Answer (score 0):

Something is not configured correctly on `habun.de` DNS configuration:

```
$ dig pine.habun.de cname

; <<>> DiG 9.18.12 <<>> pine.habun.de cname
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61266
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pine.habun.de.                 IN      CNAME
```

`pine.habun.de` does not have a CNAME record configured. The same goes for `home.habun.de`