# CNAME Record not working in local network

Tags: networking, domain, cname

Situation: I got a server at home with NextCloud on Port `8080`. With the MyFritz-adress (as DynDNS) and PortForwarding, I can reach NextCloud via `pine64.XXXXXX.myfritz.net:8080`. After some issues, I made a CNAME Record on my domain `habun.de` s.t. I can reach NextCloud via `pine.habun.de:8080`. This works perfectly fine, when I am outside my local network.

But when I am in my local network, I can reach NextCloud with `pine64.XXXXXX.myfritz.net:8080` but **NOT** with `pine.habun.de:8080`.

Why is that so? Is it because the request isn't being send outside of my network and my router can't resolve `pine.habun.de`?
How can I fix it?

**Edit:** Simple Mistake... Added the domainnames incorrectly to DNS-Rebind-Protection. I added `http://pine.habun.de` but it's just `pine.habun.de`. See Discussion to the answer of @a e

Comment: when you say "reach" your site, do you mean in a browser/client, or do you mean resolve it via a DNS lookup? it sounds like a hairpin NAT issue except that you indicate that you can "reach" the myfritz.net address. with a hairpin problem you would not be able to use the service inside your LAN unless you used a local IP address (split horizon DNS). can you please clarify if you can load the myfritz.net service in a browser or other appropriate client? also do you have a LAN DNS server, and if so, is it configured to forward upstream if it can't resolve a domain to a zone it hosts?

Comment: Yes, with "reach" I mean via browser. 
I can load myfritz.net service from local and outside network, but with `pin.habun.de:8080`only from outside.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with LAN DNS Server, but I guess I don't have one. The DNS-Server my router uses are the default one from my ISP.

Comment: and you clients point to the router? then no, there isn't a good reason that DNS would not pass on queries for your `habun.de` to your ISPs DNS servers, unless your router will allow you to specify DNS records, and you have an entry for your myfritz.net name pointing to a LAN IP like 192.168.x.y. if you did that would explain everything and you'd fix the issue by adding a similar name for pine.habun.de. if that is not the case, are you able to resolve the cname with a command like `nslookup pine.habun.de` or `nslookup pine.habun.de 8.8.8.8` [that one queries Googles DNS servers]. works for me.

Comment: My Domain is from hostinger and is registered on their NameServers (maybe that changes something). My router doesn't allow to specify DNS records and  `XXXX.myfritz.net` is the DynDNS I use to access my home network (since DS-Lite-Tunnel + IPv6). `pine64.XXXXX.myfritz.net` is pointing at my server's IP `192.168.x.y`, if I understand it correctly. I can resolve in the cname with the ǹslookup` command.

Comment: if I'm understanding your statements correctly, it sounds like `XXXX.myfritz.net`  would have a public ip in DNS. it surprises me to hear that the pine64 host in that domain has a LAN-only IP address like one starting with 192.168, since that could not work outside your LAN. that said though you mention somthing about a tunnel that I don't understand. are you establishing a VPN or application tunnel connection somewhere in this scheme? if so, when you indicate you can connect to it while outside your network, does that imply you have connected to the network via a VPN already?

Comment: I don't have a public/static IP, that's why I use the myfritz.net service (DynDNS). With PortForwarding (actually here it's called MyFritz! sharing) I opened up Port 8080 for device pine64. This automatically generateted `pine64.XXXXXX.myfritz.net:8080`and I can access NextCloud from anywhere (local network or outside). No VPN involved.
Then I defined the CNAME Record `pine.habun.de` which points to `pine64.XXXXXXX.myfritz.net`and from outside (so device not connected to local network) I can reach NextCloud via `pine.habun.de:8080` but not from the local network.
Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: I guess `XXXXXX.myfritz.net` is pointing to my router (as DynDNS) and `pine64.XXXXX.myfritz.net` is then forwarding to the device pine64. 
DS-Lite-Tunnel is this protocol to connect to IPv4 applications with an IPv6 internet connection (or smth like that). I am still pretty new to all of that stuff...

Comment: Wow, I'm at a loss. If the myfritz.net works inside and out, then its not hairpining (you must have a nice router). at this point I'd start thinking about application layer issues. what is the precise error you see when you try to connect to service using the habun.de name?

Comment: The error message is in Chrome "Thsi site can't be reached (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" and in FireFox just "Server not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router's DNS is pointing to itself and your request doesn't make it out.

Consider configuring your hosts file or your router's DNS settings to point `pine.habun.de:8080` to your NextCloud internal IP address.

Add something like this `192.168.1.100 pine.habun.de` to your hosts file if you prefer that method.

[How to edit hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Comment: With "host", do you mean the server or my domain?
I can't find any settings in my fritzbox to add any redirecting settings.

Comment: I tried adding '192.168.1.100 pine.habun.de` to the host file of the device with which I am accessing NextCloud, which made it work in the local network, but unreachable from outside...

Comment: Ahh, ok. Does changing the router dns settings do that?

Comment: I didn't find any option to do that. I have a FritzBox 7530.

Comment: Not sure that router can do it. See Frank Thomas' comment about hairpinning

Comment: Try to edit the dns rebind protection on the FritzBox.

Comment: @M.Behrens, I would not expect this situation to be commonly detected as a rebinding attack, but I see what you mean, and I could see it having some potential for impact. can you expand on what you think the rebinding protection should be set to?

Comment: I added `http://pine.habun.de:8080`, `http://pine.habun.de` and `http://habun.de`to the DNS-Rebind-Protection, rebooted the FritzBox but didn't work as well....

Comment: I think I will try to run a DNS-Server on an SBC tomorrow. That should solve the problem (at least I hope so). In that way locally the domain query will be redirected to the local IP of the server and outside it should behave as normal. Or am I missing something?

Comment: not entirely clear on what SBC is, but I do believe that hosting an internal zone for your LAN would give you more flexibility and potentially solve your issues. I use Bind9, and host a zone for my internal domain. my clients all point to it (or really they point to the pihole server that points to it) and it forwards all unresolved queries up to public DNS servers for resolution. hope it works out for you!

Comment: @PapierFlieger: I'm guessing the added entries don't work because they are _not domains_ – domain names don't have :ports and they don't have scheme:// prefixes.

Comment: It seems like it works now. I changed the entries in the dns rebind protection as @user1686 said and can connect now. It's always such little mistakes....

(SBC = SingleBoardComputer)